# Hazelcast transaction map and map store

Tags: transactions, hazelcast

I'm using `Hazelcast` with its awesome feature: transaction.

I have an `IMap` which config `MapStore` to save/load (lazy) data from backed DB.

When I use `TransactionContext.getMap(mapName).getForUpdate(key)`, does Hazelcast auto load data from MapStore for the input key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Hazelcast will attempt to load value from `MapStore` for the given key the first time it is `getForUpdate`'d in the context of the transaction.

Comment: Thank you, I have do a test and it's exactly as you said.